# Redirect security with opaque state token to SPA on login

Tags: authentication, url-redirection, identity-management, react

I am currently working on a sign-up flow on Auth0 where I need to get GDPR consent after a person does a social login. We can run serverless functions using their Actions that check if GDPR has been consented and redirects to a custom site in case the consent is missing.

### Auth0 documentation

Here is my drawing of what Auth0 proposes in [their documentation (Option 3)](https://auth0.com/docs/secure/data-privacy-and-compliance/gdpr/gdpr-track-consent-with-lock#option-3-redirect-to-another-page)

[[image: Functionality of Auth0 documentation example][1]]

- Their example redirects to a server that only delivers a rendered html form. [See here on GitHub](https://github.com/auth0/rules/blob/master/redirect-rules/simple/webtask.js)

### My situation with a SPA

- I have a **single page application that runs using react**

I don't understand the benefit of running a server to serve the static html form since there is no sensitive data here (it is only a checkbox) and the opaque state token ensures that only the user can continue the login flow.

What I did now is to redirect directly into my SPA and obtain the state from the query parameter to directly redirect to the /continue endpoint (A direct AJAX post does not work for me due to CORS issues). Which is technically fine for me since I only need to transport 1 bit of information (User has consented).

Here is a drawing of my solution:

[image]

Here is the relevant react code

```
  const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
  const state = queryParams.get("state")

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = "https://" + process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH0_DOMAIN + "/continue?state=" + state
  };
```

### Question

Is my solution is as secure as what Auth0 proposes or if there are any pitfalls I am not seeing?

**My thoughts:**
I think that the worst that can happen is that someone sends a user a link to my SPA with a malicious state query parameter `spa.com/consent?state=malicious` and gets the user to submit the form to Auth0. In that case Auth0 will reject the request. Furthermore I believe that the same issue is also present in the Auth0 example. The Auth0 example could be improved by using a signed token that they could also validate in their backend but in our case we are only transmitting 1bit of non-sensitive data and I question if I need to do that.

I am unsure if there are any pitfalls to fetching an unverified query parameter and setting `window.location.href` directly in React.